# Scala KStreams moving from many filters to split and branch

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Assuming that all undefined methods here have valid signatures.
I have the following code that works perfectly:

```
  // Add validation tags to the stream
  val validated: KStream[K, V] = stream.mapValues(x => validate(x))

  // Predicate to separate valid and invalid regions
  val isInvalid: (K, V) => Boolean = (_: K, v: V) => !v.isValid

  // Branch the rejects out of the main stream and into a rejects topic
  val incAndReject: KStream[K, V] => Unit =
    _.mapValues(f1)
      .peek(incMetric1)
      .to("bad-topic")
```

Now I have the following working snippet:

```
  validated.peek((_, v) => incMetric2(v))
  val temp = validated.filter(isInvalid)
  incAndReject(temp)
  validated.filter((_, v) => v.isValid)
```

And I am trying to change it to the, what I think is, equivalent code using split and branch instead of filter, and it doesn't work:

```
  // Branched names are for the topology, they do not affect topic names (?)
  val rejectsBranch: Branched[K, V] = Branched.withConsumer[K, V](incAndReject, "invalid-region")

  validatedEnrichedStream
    .peek((_, v) => incMetric2(v))
    .split()
    .branch(isInvalid, rejectsBranch)
    .defaultBranch()
    .head
    ._2
```

Am I doing it right? Documentation about KStreams branched streams is abysmal and only in Java

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

The key was on the keys of the map elements, that change slightly from the branch names, so `.head._2` worked while `.get("name")` didn't